# HTTP 503 response to an asmx webservice request

Tags: http, wireshark

I have some code that basically sends a HTTP POST to an asmx webservice on another server in our network. Recently, about 50% of these requests return a HTTP 503. I talked to our server guys and gave them detailed information about timestamps of theses requests and users that were affected to investigate. The response after some time was basically "nothing is wrong on our end, we were running wireshark and we don't even see the requests in your log".

So my question: is there any scenario where a request for which I get a HTTP 503 response when querying a server shows up in wireshark on that same server ? I find that very hard to believe given the nature of the response...

Answer (score 0):

#### HTTP 503

503 is a server error response. If you are seeing this response on the client, that means that the server has enough cycles to tell you to go away, but that's it. It means that there is indeed bidirectional traffic, *just not the server response you want*.

#### Potential reasons for absence in capture

It is possible that just as the server doesn't have the resources to respond to your request, it also doesn't have the resources for Wireshark to function. Wireshark will start dropping packets (or fail to function) if any of these are maxed out:

- CPU
- RAM
- Storage
- Kernel buffer size (set manually with -B in tcpdump/Wireshark, default is 2MB)

There's also the potential for human error here, with the capture coming from the wrong device, interface, or using the wrong filter.

#### Pcap *should* contain both packets

To answer your question, if you look at a packet capture on either client or server (and the conversation is not TLS-encrypted), you will see an HTTP GET for the resource and an HTTP 503 in response. If your colleagues do not see this traffic in a capture, then there is a problem with their capture or capturing methodology.

**Further Reading: 503 Capture Filter**

If you are looking for a HTTP 503 capture filter, [this article](http://insidetrust.blogspot.com/2010/10/wireshark-capture-filter-for-http-503.html) goes into greater detail.